# elastic apm can't connect to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-apm

My apm server can't connect to ES with the following log

```
2020-04-12T04:08:17.102Z        ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://example.com:9200)): Connection marked
as failed because the onConnect callback failed: resource 'apm-7.4.2-span' exists, but it is not an alias
```

I tried to 'reset' the index by the following command, it won't work either

```
$ apm-server setup --index-management
Exiting: resource 'apm-7.4.2-span' exists, but it is not an alias
```

I tried to setup a policy where apm data is deleted after 3 month, and I think I messed up the index setup.. (I can't remember what I did exactly)

How do I reset the index and start using apm again? 
(It's a plus if I can retain the data, but I can sacrifice it)

Comment: Got the same error today due to a restart. Should I delete all my apm indexes ?

Comment: i was able to connect after reverting the change I made to apm-server.yml

Comment: I didn't do any changes, just restarted my server and now apm-server cannot connect

Comment: make sure that you only have one Index Template that match the index that will be created by apm server (or filebeat, metricbeat and so on)